doFuture and LSF
I am currently calculating sample size that is very heavy computationally, but it takes advantage of the R-package doFuture:
library(MAMS)
plan(multisession, workers = 12)
mams(K=4, J=3, alpha=0.05, power=0.9, r=1:3, r0=1:3, p=0.65, p0=0.55, 
     ushape="triangular", lshape="triangular", nstart=30)

I would like to use the HPC to run the above code but considering different several scenarios for the parameters. I learned that the job scheduler used in the HPC is LSF. Therefore, I prepared the batch file as follow:
#!/bin/bash
#BSUB -J mams
#BSUB -P acc_user
#BSUB -q premium
#BSUB -n 24
#BSUB -W 120:00
#BSUB -oo %J.stdout
#BSUB -eo %J.stderr
 
#BSUB -L /bin/bash

module load openmpi
module load R

R CMD BATCH --no-save --no-restore '--args nc=2' sample_size.R output.Rout

I modified the argument of function plan from multisession to cluster in my R code following the documentation of doFuture (https://future.futureverse.org/reference/plan.html)
library(MAMS)
plan(cluster, workers = 12)
mams(K=4, J=3, alpha=0.05, power=0.9, r=1:3, r0=1:3, p=0.65, p0=0.55, 
     ushape="triangular", lshape="triangular", nstart=30)

However, the HPC admin told me that I have been using the resources inefficiently as my job cannot utilize cores on multiple nodes. Therefore, they asked me to add "#BSUB -R span[hosts=1]" in my batch file, which I did.
My question: How can I make doFuture use cores on multiple nodes on the HPC using LSF?

How many cores do you have on one node? If 12, use #BSUB -n 1 to request only one node and plan(multicore, workers=12) to engage 12 cores on the one node. The multicore plan uses shared memory unix fork. It is possible to use multiple nodes with OpenMPI and all cores in R but I am not sure if MAMS is configured for distributed memory.
